# Kotlin Multiplatform : Plugin [id: 'com.android.library'] was not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to set up Android Library via Kotlin Multiplatform Library.

I am getting error:

`Plugin [id: 'com.android.library'] was not found in any of the following sources:`

Please help me by pointing out what is wrong and how to resolve this issue.

My plugin set up is this(with supposedly proper buildscript):

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization").version("1.3.72")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform").version("1.3.72")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}
```

when I replace that with following

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform").version("1.3.72")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization").version("1.3.72")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.squareup.sqldelight'
```

it's working fine. 
I am not sure what causes the issue.

Following is the  complete build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization").version("1.3.72")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform").version("1.3.72")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}

group 'com.jolas.sdk.kn.newsycore'
version '0.0.1'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

def ktor_version = '1.3.2'
kotlin {
    android {
        publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
    }
    // This is for iPhone simulator
    // Switch here to iosArm64 (or iosArm32) to build library for iPhone device
    iosX64("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework()
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version"
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
            }
        }
        androidMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib')
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktor_version"
                implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:sqlite-driver:1.3.0"
            }
        }
        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib')
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktor_version"
                implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:1.3.0"
            }
        }
    }
}

sqldelight {
    NewsyDatabase {
        packageName = "com.jolas.sdk.kn.newsycore"
    }
}

configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
```

Comment: Hello, @Harley! Can you please add more details about your error? There should also be a list of sources, maybe the one with this plugin is missing.

Comment: Sure. @ArtyomDegtyarev. Please download this project https://github.com/jolasjoe/newsy-core you'll find the build.gradle file in root-dir. In that file, if you remove the line apply plugin: 'com.android.library' and add id("com.android.library") under plugins section you will be able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Nelson is correct regarding the `pluginManagement` block, but there is an additional requirement for a plugin to be found without additional configuration. If you require `plugins { id("com.android.application") version "3.6.1" }`, Gradle would search for the following Maven artifact: `com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:3.6.1`. This is a convention. When developing your custom plugin, Gradle's default `java-gradle-plugin` will provide such an artifact out of the box. See [the corresponding section of Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers) for more details.

To override module resolution for any plugin, you can use the `resolutionStrategy` block. I've got the following for Android plugins:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.namespace == "com.android") {
                useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:${requested.version}")
            } else if(requested.id.namespace == "com.google.gms") {
                useModule("com.google.gms:${requested.id.name}:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Having this in your `settings.gradle.kts` will allow you to use the usual `plugins` block as follows:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "3.6.1"
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.3.3"
}
```

Of course, to re-use the same version of the plugin in all submodules you can go with the usual route of `apply false`:

**/build.gradle.kts**:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "3.6.1" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "3.6.1" apply false
    // ...
}
```

**/lib/build.gradle.kts**:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugins block gets its dependencies from the pluginManagement block in `settings.gradle` not the `build.gradle` buildscript block.
Please add the following to your `settings.gradle` file and try again.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue still occurs, Nelson. Please download the project from https://github.com/jolasjoe/newsy-core and please see if you can make your solution work.